# How to change size of text_area_tag helper in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I have a text area and below is the corresponding code for that. I want to change the number of rows it contains and the want the text area to fill the screen horizontally on mobile. How do I change. I am new to ruby on rails and couldn't figure out the right syntax to add rows.

```
<div class="control-group">
        <%= label_tag(:message_body, "Body", :class => "control-label") %>
        <div class="controls">
        <%= text_area_tag :message_body,  @message_body %>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref [`text_area_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002245)

```
<%= text_area_tag :message_body,  @message_body, :size =>"25x10" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text_area_tag 'message_body', nil, :rows => 10, :cols => 25
# => <textarea cols="25" id="body" name="body" rows="10"></textarea>
```

More info - [Text Area Tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002245)