# How can I make this text_area_tag field larger?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using mailboxer gem and have this code:

```
  <%= label :body, "Message text" %>
  <p><%= text_area_tag :body %></p>
```

How can I make the text_area_tag section larger and generally insert css styling?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use CSS, but see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896537/should-i-size-a-textarea-with-css-width-height-or-html-cols-rows-attributes) where using both HTML and CSS is advocated.

So with the view erb:

```
<div class="body_input">
  <%= label :body, "Message text" %>
  <p><%= text_area_tag :body, @body %></p>
</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.body_input textarea {
  width: 30em;
  heigth: 15em;
}
```

The CSS width and height you can alter to match your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I have to reference the :body and it works.

```
  <%= label :body, "Message text" %>
  <p><%= text_area_tag :body, @body, :size =>"25x10" %></p>
```

From this answer: [How to change size of text_area_tag helper in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597966/how-to-change-size-of-text-area-tag-helper-in-ruby-on-rails)